# Success part not working in .ajax()

Tags: jquery

I have a recursive function called `generateHtml` which is called within form submitting function.

I am having an issue with the `success` part. Even if I remove the content of success part and just put alert, it doesn't work. It doesn't show up with any error either.

```
function generateHtml(count,total,pars,files) {

    if (count == 1) {
        f = 'f=';
        allfiles = files;
        allpars = pars;
    }

    fn = randomToN(99999999, 0);
    f = f + fn + '|';
    dat = allpars + "&file=" + allfiles[count] + "&fn=" + fn + '&i=' + count;
    alert(dat);

    $.ajax({
        url: "../../ii/getindreports.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: dat,
        async:true,
        dataType: 'html',
        error: function () {
            alert('ERROR !!!!');
        },
        complete: function () {
            alert('test');
            //  -------------------------Success part---------------//
            $('#merobar').html( $('#merobar').html() + '<br>Report '+ count +' Compiled.');

            // if count not equal to total we still have html to process so call the function again
            if (count != total) {
                count = count + 1;
                alert(count);
                generateHtml(count, total, 0, 0);
            } else {
                alert('make pdf now ');
                fnpdf = randomToN(99999999, 0);
                f = f + '&pdf=' + fnpdf;

                $.ajax({
                    url: "../../ii/makebulkhtmlpdf.php",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: f,
                    async:true,
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function () {
                        //alert('<br>Report Generation Completed');
                        $('#merobar').html( $('#merobar').html() + '<br>Report Generation Completed');
                        $('#merobar').html( $('#merobar').html() + '<br><a href=\"../../temp/temp_'+fnpdf+'.pdf\" target=\"_blank\">Click To Download</a>');
                    }
                });
            }//end of else
                    //  -------------------------Success part--------------//
        }//end of success
    });// end of  first .ajax function
    return true;
}//end of function

$('#sliderform').submit(function() {
    //alert("here");
    var files = new Array();
    var checked = $("input:checkbox[name=files]:checked").length > 0;

    if (!checked) {
        alert("Please select at least one Report");
        return false;
    }

    i = 1;
    $("input:checkbox[name=files]:checked").each(function () {
        //alert($(this).val());
        if ($(this).val() != '') {
            files[i] = $(this).val();
            i = i + 1;
        }
    });//end of .each

    //alert(files);
    $('#merobar').html('File Processing ...');
    pars = $(this).serialize();
    total = $("input:checkbox[name=files]:checked").length;

    generateHtml(1,total,pars,files);
});//end of submit function
```

Comment: Would you mind formatting your code part with correct indentations, so it becomes easier to read?

Comment: Just some style pointers: use the `var` keyword to declare variables; keep your code indented consistently for readability's sake. Also, to your question: `complete()` is not the "success" callback, `success()` is.

Comment: Hello I had success before so I was trying with success . It seems to be working in IE though . doest work in chrome

Comment: Please  consider indenting your code consistently and using whitespace judiciously; having a hard time seeing everything that's important.

Comment: @DaveNewton: I tried to clean it up a bit.

Comment: really sorry regarding the indentation

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what this will do, but I rewrote all of your code closer to the way that I would do things, adding good style practices and appropriately declaring variables that aren't meant to be global.

I didn't see anything syntactically wrong with your code other than the missing `var` keywords, so if something isn't working there might be other code somewhere with syntax issues preventing the code from your post from running.

```
function generateHtml(count, total, pars, files) {

    var f = '';
    var allfiles = [];
    var allpars = [];
    var fn = 0;

    if (count == 1) {
        f = 'f=';
        allfiles = files;
        allpars = pars;
    }

    fn = randomToN(99999999, 0);
    f = f + fn + '|';
    dat = allpars + "&file=" + allfiles[count] + "&fn=" + fn + '&i=' + count;
    alert(dat);

    $.ajax({
        url: "../../ii/getindreports.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: dat,
        async: true,
        dataType: 'html',
        error: function () {
            alert('ERROR !!!!');
        },
        complete: function () {
            alert('test');
            //  -------------------------Success part---------------//
            $('#merobar').append('<br>Report '+ count +' Compiled.');

            // if count not equal to total we still have html to process so call the function again
            if (count != total) {
                count = count + 1;
                alert(count);
                generateHtml(count, total, 0, 0);
            } else {
                alert('make pdf now ');
                var fnpdf = randomToN(99999999, 0);
                f = f + '&pdf=' + fnpdf;

                $.ajax({
                    url: "../../ii/makebulkhtmlpdf.php",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: f,
                    async:true,
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function () {
                        //alert('<br>Report Generation Completed');
                        $('#merobar').append('<br>Report Generation Completed');
                        $('#merobar').append('<br><a href=\"../../temp/temp_' + fnpdf + '.pdf\" target=\"_blank\">Click To Download</a>');
                    }
                });
            }//end of else
                    //  -------------------------Success part--------------//
        }//end of success
    });// end of  first .ajax function
    return true;
}//end of function

$('#sliderform').submit(function() {
    //alert("here");
    var files = [];
    var checked = $("input[name=files]:checked").length > 0;

    if (!checked) {
        alert("Please select at least one Report");
        return false;
    }

    var i = 1;
    $("input[name=files]:checked").each(function () {
        //alert($(this).val());
        if ($(this).val() != '') {
            files.push($(this).val());
        }
    });//end of .each

    //alert(files);
    $('#merobar').html('File Processing ...');
    var pars = $(this).serialize();
    var total = $("input[name=files]:checked").length;

    generateHtml(1, total, pars, files);
});//end of submit function
```